# How to use onCheckboxClicked method in android

Tags: android, checkbox, toolbar

I have an array of checkboxes in android and I would like to set the onclick listener when one or more checkboxes are selected. I followed the documentation from android : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html

but I do not know how do I call the method onCheckboxClicked after I declare it.

My code is as follows:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.selectButton) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvMain.getChildCount(); i++) {
            LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) lvMain.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
            cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cb.setChecked(false);


        }
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.selectAllButton) {


        for (int i = 0; i < lvMain.getChildCount(); i++) {
            LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) lvMain.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
            cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cb.setChecked(true);


        }

          return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onCheckBoxClicked(View v) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
    int numOfChecked = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <lvMain.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if(listitems.get(i).equals(checked)) {
            numOfChecked++;
        }

        Toolbar toolbar_bottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
        toolbar_bottom.setTitle(numOfChecked + " items selected." + lvMain.getChildAt(i));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar_bottom);
        toolbar_bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

}
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    >
</CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically what I wanna achieve is to update the bottom toolbar to display how many items are currently selected. Whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked it will automatically update the count. Any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.cbBox:
            if (checked)
                // Do something
            else
                // Do something else
            break;
        case R.id.checkbox_cheese:
            if (checked)
                // Cheese me
            else
                // I'm lactose intolerant
            break;
        // TODO: Veggie sandwich
    }
}
```

You are calling **onOptionsItemSelected** method which is for MenuItems. Don't use that use above code.

Comment: Hi, sorry while copy pasting my code I left out the onCheckBoxClicked method which I already declared earlier, its at the bottom, I just edited it. Any idea where do I call this method ?